# Angularjs Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received: {} in typeahead

Tags: angularjs, typeahead

I have been trying to implement typeahead functionality in my mockup , where the table content refreshes as the value of the typeahead changes but it throws an error stating,

> Angularjs Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received: {}

```js
vm.getEnterprises = function(term){
            vm.selected = undefined;
            return $http.get(path +'/enterprise/'+ term + '/search')
            .then(function(response){
              
                vm.customEnterprises = response.data;
                vm.showcontent = true;
                vm.defaultcontent = false;
                return response.data;
                console.log(response);
            });
        }
```

I use MongoDB with Mongoose ORM in Node for backend, the API code is,

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var enterprise = mongoose.model('enterprise');

var search = function(req, res){

       
        var name = req.params.name;
        var regexValue = '\.*' + name ;
        
  enterprise.find({'name': new RegExp(regexValue, 'i')},function(err, data){
   if (err){
    console.log('err',err);
   } else {
    return res.json(data);
    console.log(data);
   }
  });
}
module.exports = {
 searchEnterprise : search
};
```

My Angular UI code is,

```
input type="text" id="search" ng-model = "vm.selected" class="form-control input-md enable collapse" placeholder="search for an enterprise" uib-typeahead = "name as enterprise.name for enterprise in vm.getEnterprises($viewValue)| filter:$viewValue | limitTo : 3 ">
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you aware `filter` only accepts `Array` as an input, your `vm.getEnterprises` basically return a promise object not the actual data.

What you need to do is just assign your return data to a scope level variable (i.e. the same scope as your template) e.g. `$scope.retData` then change your template to

```
name as enterprise.name for enterprise in retData | filter:$viewValue | limitTo : 3
```

Comment: vm.getEnterprises($viewValue) calls the function which makes the API call at the back end if i change it $scope.retdata where do that calling will be done.

Comment: What I meant is inside your `vm.getEnterprises` instead of `return response.data` assign the response data to a scope level variable and make sure your template can access it, then change `in vm.getEnterprises($viewValue)` to that variable

Comment: Btw, just in case, I guess you don't need the `return` for `$http.get` as well. So your function `vm.getEnterprises` basically doesn't return anything but call API to fetch data then store the data to that scope level variable. Then `uib-typehead` should detect changes of that scope level variable once the promise was resolved.

Comment: @BrianLiu I don't think you answered his question. If he replaces the call to getEnterprises with a scope variable, getEnterprises will never be called and the scope variable will never be initialized to anything.